# Adding current time played to total time played

Tags: time, lua

I have a database with the total played game time in seconds. I want to fetch these seconds from the database, add the current session play time in seconds and then update the database.
This should happen every 5 seconds. I have done this, but because I do `currentSession + totalTimePlayedDB` it keeps adding the **full duration** of my current session over and over... Any ideas?

```
local currentPlayTime = player:TimeConnected()
print(math.Round(currentPlayTime))
local playerValues = MySQLite.queryValue([[SELECT time FROM chiz_time WHERE sid=']].. player:SteamID() ..[[']], function(time)
    if time == "" then 
        time = math.Round(currentPlayTime)

        else
            time = math.Round(time + time - currentPlayTime )
    end

    MySQLite.query([[UPDATE chiz_time SET time = ']].. time ..[[' WHERE sid=']].. player:SteamID() ..[[']])     
end)
```

Comment: Code? I read twice, and I still don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: Updating a DB value every 5 seconds seems highly inefficient. Couldn't you simply update the total time played once, like when the player disconnects, the game is over, etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do `currentSession` + `totalTimePlayedDB` it keeps adding the full duration of my current

You just need to compute the delta from your last save time.

In your init code somewhere:

```
lastSaveTime = 0
```

In your save routine:

```
totalTimePlayedDB = totalTimePlayedDB + currentSession - lastSaveTime
if (totalTimePlayedDB is written to the database successfully) then
   lastSaveTime = currentSession
end
```